# python - overflow encountered in exp with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy to do some calculations, and`np.exp(1000)` keeps getting `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp` error. I suppose it's because `exp^1000` is too big to be stored in float64, but I can't seem to find away around this. I tried long double and floa128(suggested by some answers that I found on stackoverflow, but it doesn't seem to work, because it keeps saying there's no np.float128??)

Comment: The main question is why do you want `np.exp(1000)`? I'm sure you can rewrite your computation to avoid such crazy big numbers...

Comment: It is impossible to represent this number, even using `str`.

Comment: I am watching an University online course and doing it's homework. One of it's homework questions requires this kind of computations(for softmax funciton).

Comment: As I said I doubt it is required, I'm pretty sure you can circumvent this crazy values with a bit of math, for (basic) example you don't need to compute `exp(1000)` and `exp(1002)` to compute `exp(1002)/exp(1000)` which is just `exp(2)`

Comment: Hmmm, another [softmax question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnumpy%5D+softmax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's for softmax computation, you can subtract the greatest value of all your outputs, without changing the softmax values, and this way you won't have crazy large numbers, only values smaller than 1 as a matter of fact.

example:

SM(1000,1001) = SM(0,1) = 1/(1+e) , e/(1+e)